# RestSharp issues when sending SOAP style Request

Tags: c#, xml, soap, restsharp

I recently implemented RestSharp instead of using plain old HTTP client in .NET Core.  This was too help with some OAuth1 authentication problems and it worked great.

However, one requirement I need to support is now broken - a call to an old version of NAV that still uses a SOAP envelope and XML.

My RestSharp request is built like this (partially redacted):

```
var request = new RestRequest(transmission.Url.PathAndQuery, Helper.GetRestSharpMethod(transmission.Method), dataType);

request.AddParameter("text/xml", body, "text/xml", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Where dataType is Datatype.Xml and body is my soap envelope as XML text.  I've tried "application/xml".  I've also tried using request.AddBody and request.AddBodyXml - but they just caused more issues.

The endpoint (which we know works with the old request) returns an issue with being unable to read data from inside the SOAP envelope (which again we know is there, because it's in the parameters of the request).

Can anybody suggest any ways of fixing this issue and still using rest sharp?  Or is this not really intended to be supported, and I'd be better off using plain HTTP Client for this specific part?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Concerning the old code, SOAP envelope text is identical.  The difference is that instead of using RestSharp request.AddBody(), I built standard HttpRequestMessage, then set the HttpContent as `new StringContent(content)`

This was sent using standard .NET Core httpclient

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: See end of following posting : https://forum.mibuso.com/discussion/39037/nav-web-services-soap-envelope-parameters.  If this doesn't help I would use a sniffer to compare working and non work app and compare http headers.  You need to add/modify a header to get it to work.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look into this now...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this helps - the SOAP XML sent in the original request works, and is identical in the new RestSharp request

Comment: Do you have old code where NAV worked?

Comment: Added some old code info...unfortunately difficult to add in as it was spread over several classes.   Basically it was just a case of creating a new HttpRequestMessage, creating the SOAP content (as HttpContent) and then setting the content of the RequestMessage to that - all very standard.

Comment: So what is the sniffer show that is different?

Comment: It'll take me some time to get it up and running, will have to go into source control history and extract the old version

Answer (score 2):

Ok finally got the to the bottom of this - posting here just in case anybody else has similar issues.

First of all - yes, it is supported.

- However, there are a number of gotchas along the way - RestSharp
  automagically handles escaped `URL` strings.  Don't escape them
  yourself.
- Use `request.AddParameter` with `ParameterType.RequestBody` instead of
  request.AddBody.
- When creating the rest client, be sure to give it the full `URI` when
  using basic authentication (I was using partial base address for
  `OAuth1`, and carried it over).
- When creating `IRestRequest`, be careful with supplying additional parameters like `DataFormat`, as removing this seemed to help resolve the problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve the problem:

```cs
var client = new RestClient(requestUrl);
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
request.AddParameter("text/xml", requestBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: "I think it will solve." So.. you don't know, did not try and cannot explain how it is supposed to work and why that might help to solve the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide some explanation why do you think your proposed solution might help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with differing results based on .NET 4.8 vs .NET 7.0... and different versions of RestSharp. Here are the two variants with success based on the differing versions.

- .NET 4.8 / RestSharp: 106.11.7 (depreciated)

```
var client = new RestClient(targetUri);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.None;
request.AddParameter("SOAPAction", postData, ParameterType.RequestBody);

var response = client.Execute(request);
if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    return response.Content;
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Soap Request Failed");
}
```

- .NET Standard 7.0 / RestSharp: 110.1.0

```
var client = new RestClient(targetUri);
var request = new RestRequest();
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.None;
request.AddStringBody(postData, DataFormat.Xml);

var response = await client.ExecutePostAsync(request);
if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    return response.Content;
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Soap Request Failed");
}
```